# Combine non-adjacent cells in a named range to use in a chart

Tags: excel, charts, series, named-ranges

I'm working on a C# Excel Add-in and I want to draw a chart. The chart will display mean values from 3 ranges of data named **ST_2006**, **ST_2007** and **ST_2008**.

1. This 1st approach is working. A series with a name **Mean** and 2 arrays with data. This is a static chart that won't update if the source data is updated.

   ```
   =SERIES("Mean",{500,600,700},{0.166666666666667,0.5,0.833333333333333},4)
   ```
2. For my 2nd try I added the formulas. This doesn't give an error but treats them as a string value. Removing the **""** gives me the error below. After removing the **""** than removing **=** gives the same error.

   ```
   =SERIES("Mean",{"=AVERAGE(ST_2006)","=AVERAGE(ST_2007)","=AVERAGE(ST_2008)"},{0.166666666666667,0.5,0.833333333333333},4)
   ```

[image]

3. My 3rd attempt was to calculate the means with **=AVERAGE(ST_2006)**, **=AVERAGE(ST_2007)** and **=AVERAGE(ST_2008)**, naming them and using those names in the chart like below. *('Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2006_MEAN refers to =AVERAGE(ST_2006) for example)* Unfortunately I get the same error as in attempt 2.

   ```
   =SERIES("Mean",{'Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2006_MEAN,'Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2007_MEAN,'Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2008_MEAN},{0.166666666666667,0.5,0.833333333333333},4)
   ```
4. I've also come across suggestions saying I probably could do the thing below. This would then be named something like **ST_MEANS** but this doesn't work properly. If I'd define a name (TEST) that refers to `=500,600,700` and I place this in a cell `=TEST`, the cell will show 500. If I try to do this with the means, the cell shows #VALUE!.

   ```
   ='Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2006_MEAN,'Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2007_MEAN,'Box - Whisker Plot 1'!ST_2008_MEAN
   ```

The following link is a test file I'm working with: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9yxzg2ppouje6w/Book1.xlsx?dl=0. I created the named ranges and from cell B13 down I'm trying to get the array to work but without luck. The goal is to use the named range in the chart.

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you just calculate the means for each series using the AVERAGE function within the actual worksheet and then add that as a series?

Comment: Because I'm not allowed to write anything in the sheet.